# Mock function call with mockbox that needs to both throw and not throw

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, coldbox

I'm using Mockbox to write tests and have a function I need to test that looks like this

```
public void function placeOrder() {
  // do stuff
  local.helper = variables.injector.getInstance("orderHelper");
  local.args = { a = "hi", b = "bye" };
  try {
    invoke(local.helper, "print", local.args);  // Call 1
  }
  catch (any e) {
    local.args.tryOtherPrinter = true;
    invoke(local.helper, "print", local.args);  // Call 2
  }
  // do stuff
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to test `placeOrder` and mock the `print` call so that it will throw an exception the first time and not the second time.  The key, I think, is that the arguments passed in will be different each time, but if I don't nail them, it doesn't map correctly to my mock and won't throw the exception.

Here's my test code so far:

```
// local.order and local.helper are mocks
local.printArgs = { a = "hi", b = "bye" };
local.printArgs2 = { a = "hi", b = "bye", tryOtherPrinter = true };
// should you be able to do this and it'll throw based on the args...
local.helper.$(method = "print", throwException = true).$args(local.printArgs).$results("");
// ... and not throw based on the other args?
local.helper.$(method = "print").$args(local.printArgs2).$results("");
local.order.placeOrder();
assertEquals(2, local.helper.$count("print"), "Expected print to be called twice");
```

I know [in the docs](https://testbox.ortusbooks.com/content/mockbox/mocking_methods/results_method.html) that you can have it return different results on subsequent calls, but in this case I need it to throw, then not throw and it looks like when you mock a method it's fairly set in stone as to whether you are asking it to throw or not throw.